# Certificados SSL para 3 web en el mismo servidor

Tags: web, servidor, ssl

Necesito instalar certificados SSL para 3 web que están en un mismo servidor. He estado leyendo y creo que si tienen la misma IP no es posible pero no entiendo muy bien lo de la misma IP. Me imagino que el servidor sí tendrá la misma IP pero los dominios no.
Los certificados los conseguiría de Let´s Encrypt pero a ver si me pueden guiar en cómo instalarlos y si es posible. En principio no contemplo el Certificado Multidominio. El servidor es de Hostalia y creo que es dedicado.
Cualquier ayuda o comentario será bienvenido.

Comment: Esa inquietud comentala a quien emitirá el/los certificado(s); hata donde tengo entendido cada sitio debe tener su propio certificado.

Comment: @RobertoLeónOramas, los [certificados SAN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subject_Alternative_Name) permiten múltiples CN normales o comodín en un mismo certificado. En la actualidad su uso está mucho más extendido que el de las [extensiones SNI](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication). Un mismo certificado puede estar instalado en varios servidores (por ejemplo en una agrupación de alta disponibilidad o una red de distribución de contenido) e incluso en diferentes servicios (servidor web, correo, FTP, etc).

Answer (score 1):

Este es un problema que se solventó con el uso de las [extensiones SNI](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication) de TLS detalladas en la [RFC3546](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3546.txt) (a parte de los [certificados comodín](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Certificado_comod%C3%ADn) y [los certificados SAN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subject_Alternative_Name)).

El problema radicaba en que el navegador debe establecer y asegurar la conexión HTTPS ([apretón de manos](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Handshaking)) ***ANTES*** de poder enviar la [cabecera `host`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Host) que permite al servidor elegir entre un sitio web virtual u otro.

Por desgracia las extensiones SNI [no están soportadas por todos los navegadores](http://wiki.cacert.org/VhostTaskForce#Clients), además, [tampoco por todos los servidores web](http://wiki.cacert.org/VhostTaskForce#Server_support).

Apache tiene un ejemplo de [cómo configurar un servidor apache con varios certificados sobre una misma dirección IP](https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/NameBasedSSLVHostsWithSNI).

Para otros servidores web habría que consultar la compatibilidad en el manual del producto.

Si el servidor es dedicado, tal y como indicas, es probable que puedas usar SNI, en caso contrario deberías contactar con soporte de tu proveedor para conocer la forma en la que se podría activar o usar dicha extensión en su servicio.